# dozer - map object properties within list to an array

Tags: list, dozer

im trying to map a property inside an object in a list to an array and I want to know if I could do this without a custom converter.

```
public class Kid(){
    List<Toy> toys;
}
public class Toy(){
     String name;
     String brand;
}
public class ConvertedKid(){
    String[] toysNames;
}
```

After mapper.map(aKid, ConvertedKid.class) I would like to have convertedKid.toysNames as an array of strings only with its names.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you could do it with a custom converter.

Another solution I found is to **override the toString() method of Toy**.

**Toy class**

```
public class Toy{
  String name;
  String brand;

  // getters and setters ...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
  <mapping>
    <class-a>xxx.xxx.Kid</class-a>
    <class-b>xxx.xxx.ConvertedKid</class-b>
      <field>
    <a>toys</a>
    <b>toysNames</b>
      </field>
  </mapping>
```

I tested it. It works.